# com.apple.dock.plist is changed in macOS14.0 and later

Tags: xcode, macos, dock

Currently, we are working on the enterprise project that using data in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist to get detail design of the original Dock (as autohide, orientation).
It still has been worked until macOS 13.* as description as below:
[image]

But, It has been changed in macOS 14.*
[image]

Is there any alternative method to do that in macOS 14.* and later?

Code I used to get:

```
 if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "com.apple.dock"),
           let orientation = defaults.string(forKey: "orientation") {
    }
}
```

Comment: Ask not what com.apple.dock.plist can do for you.  Ask what Script Editor can do for your app.

Comment: On my Mac (macOS 14), orientation is still in com.apple.dock.plist. Did you change the orientation?

Comment: @Willeke I dont intent to change the Dock's orientation. I just want to get the current dock's detail status from macOS.

Comment: I meant: Did you look at com.apple.dock.plist after changing the orientation? It's not saved if you never changed it.

Comment: @Willeke I looked at my plist file, there is nothing added, even though I changed the dock to other position. My macOS version is 14.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get this Apple Script can help me. My bad that I dont seek for the Apple Scripts for more.

```
tell application "System Events" to set dockProperties to screen edge of dock preferences
```